# logout and redirecting session in php

Tags: php

the below one is the link in my php site.. after clicking this button the user's session should be terminated and he should be redirected again to the home page.. i have written the coding for this concept as follows but it shows me only a blank page(it is not redirected to the home page).. 
please correct my codings

```
<a href="Logout.php">
click here to log out</a>
```

codings in the Logout.php a follows

```
<?
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
ob_start();
header("location:home.php");
ob_end_flush(); 
include 'home.php';
//include 'home.php';
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Only this is necessary

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["nome"]);  // where $_SESSION["nome"] is your own variable. if you do not have one use only this as follow **session_unset();**
header("Location: home.php");
```

Comment: All right, nice it is working for you. 
The session is something very strange at a first glance, but once you learned how to use you will never forget it. :-)

Answer (score 23):

Use this instead:

```
<?
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();

header("location:home.php");
exit();
?>
```

Comment: it is not working .. i dont know the reason.. otherthings works very well except the logout page

Comment: use ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); before sesson_start and see if any errors popup ( tough it shouldn't )

Comment: "Fernando Costa's" answer worked for me ..i thank you too for ur immediate response

Comment: session_unset() is unnecesary.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: home.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

session_start();

session_unset();

session_destroy();

header("location:home.php");

exit();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php //initialize the session if (!isset($_SESSION)) {   session_start(); } 
// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
    $logoutAction .= "&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); 
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")) {
    // to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session variables
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
    $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
    unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);  
    unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
    unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);
    $logoutGoTo = "index.php";

    if ($logoutGoTo) {
        header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
        exit;
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Please don't just post code-only answers. Please explain why your code is the answer.

Comment: ahahaha responding to @LeeTaylor by a line of code, I don't know if I want to cry or to laugh

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to log out and redirect back to the login or index:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
    $_SESSION = array(); 
    session_destroy(); 
    header("Location: login.php"); // Or wherever you want to redirect
    exit();
?>
```